# How to get AWS STS using Federated User?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-sts

I'm trying to get temporary STS credentials through a federated user via a corporate account. Corporate policy doesn't allow the use of IAM users and authentication is done through AD.

Using the AWS Cli, I am trying this, but receive an error

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<ID>:role/aws-service-role/ecs.amazonaws.com/<role> --role-session-name "Rolesession1" --external-id <federated user login> --debug
```

AWS Config:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json

[default]
aws_access_key_id =
aws_secret_access_key =
aws_session_token =
```

Stacktrace:

An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the AssumeRole operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
2019-01-29 09:15:54,986 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255

An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the AssumeRole operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got this working. It's a 2 step process for now.

1. I used this code [Amazon Provided STS credential refresh](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awsiammedia/public/sample/SAMLAPICLIADFS/samlapi.py). This will write your credentials to `~/.aws/credentials`. Your username and password are what you login to your corporate network with.
2. You can now use the AWS_CLI to access AWS API's. This will also work with Ansible playbooks. You will need to lookup the credentials from the `~/.aws/credential` file either by putting them in a `vars.yaml` file, or directly in your playbook like this:

```
ec2_access_key: "{{ lookup('ini', 'aws_access_key_id section=saml file=~/.aws/credentials') }}"
ec2_secret_key: "{{ lookup('ini', 'aws_secret_access_key section=saml file=~/.aws/credentials') }}"
ec2_security_token: "{{ lookup('ini', 'aws_session_token section=saml file=~/.aws/credentials') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure SAML on your Active Directory (using ADFS) and federate AWS CLI through SAML.

This article gives step by step instructions how to do it : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/adfs-grant-ad-access-api-cli/

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, I should have also mentioned that there is a SAML Identity Provider configured as well. Can I use that for authentication? Would I use my SSO login credentials and call that endpoint?

Comment: It is not clear if your SAML provider is your AD or if you are referring about two different systems.  Your IT Security will provide guidance on which system to use if these are two different systems.  My point is that if you authenticate on a SAML identity provider, you can federate to the AWS CLI as described in the documentation.  Your IT Security team has to configure both systems (the SAML identity provider and the AWS console) to allow for such federation.

Comment: The SAML provider is the AD, however configured in AWS IAM Identity Providers is an entry for ''SSOPROD". I believe this is what links AWS to the corporate AD.